# Running published project in other computer

Tags: vb.net, installation, release, publish

I have done developing and tried debugger and the code run fine in my laptop, but when Publishing or even using Release mode and than using it in other computers it show null exception

in this part of code

```
     For Each r As DataRow In Access.dbDataTable.Rows
        Check = r("EmployeeType")
    Next
```

this one used in login Form and yes I forget to mention I use Access DB
I am really confused it's work fine than why it show exception

by the way my connection string

```
Dim mypath = Application.StartupPath & "\test.accdb"
Dim mypassword = "test"
Private dbConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & mypath & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & mypassword)
```

exception shown is NullRefrenceException

Comment: I know what MS-Access is but no idea what that `Access` object is (class object? Module?  form?) but if it is Nothing or they connection fails and so the datatable isnt created, then the `For Each` line will throw a NRE.  You need to add a bunch of defensive code to check each step and/or log each step to know how far it gets.

Comment: Also, please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem if anyone got same problem 
try to check the version of ms access it should have same version
also check connection string

```
Private dbConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & mypath & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & mypassword)
```

Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Need to be changed to same version of ms access targeted PC